# Google Play error - Error while retrieving information from server [DF-SA-01]

Tags: android, google-play, installation

I am getting this error when I am trying to install an app via the [Google Play](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play) service with my Android 2.3.6.:

> Error while retrieving information from server [DF-SA-01]***

This started to happen just recently, and I cannot install any app from Google Play service.

How can I fix it?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/ is actually a better place to ask this question

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a user-level problem, not software development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Samsung Galaxy S, I resolved the error [DF-SA-01] by selecting 'Settings', 'Application Manager', choose 'All', looked for 'Play Store' / Android Market, pressed 'Clear data' and / or uninstall updates.

Restart your phone. Try if you can install your app now. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all the mentioned methods, but without success. An alternative method to download an app from Play Store is to download from the web (PC/Laptop). That will auto install on your Android phone.