# Error retrieving information from server DF-SA-01

Tags: error-handling

While using Play store in my tablet i am facing "Error retrieving information from server DF-SA-01" this error . Now I can't download single app. Please help me .
Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234554)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Play error - Error while retrieving information from server \[DF-SA-01\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234554/google-play-error-error-while-retrieving-information-from-server-df-sa-01)